# Conditional Rendering in React on button click

Tags: reactjs

I want to conditional render component on button click,
I wrote the following code but it's not working,
when I click on comic, the comic component should be loaded,
and when I click on contest button, contest component should be loaded,
Can someone help me through this
Below are the code and the CSS file

```js
class Head extends Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
         buttonId: null
        }
        this.setButton = this.setButton.bind(this);
      }
      setButton(id){
        this.setState({buttonId: id});
      }
    render(){
        if(this.state.buttonId == 1){
            <Comic/>
        }
        else if(this.state.buttonId == 2){
            <Contest/>
        }
        else {
            <Comic/>
        }
        return(
        <div>
             <input className={this.state.buttonId === 1? "button1 orange" : 
              "button1"} onClick={() => this.setButton(1)} value="Comic" 
               type="button" ref="button" />
            <input className={this.state.buttonId === 2? "button2 orange" : 
            "button2"} onClick={() => this.setButton(2)}  value="Contest" 
             ref="button1" type="button" />
         
         </div>
         );
       }
    }

export default Head;
```

```css
      input[type="button"]{
    background-color: white;
  }
    input[type="button"].orange{
    background-color: orange;
  }
```

Comment: In the conditional logic at the start of your render function you aren't returning the components.

Comment: E.g. `if (this.state.buttonId==1) return <Comic/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not returning your components, try the following:

```
class Head extends Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
         buttonId: null
        }
        this.setButton = this.setButton.bind(this);
      }
      setButton(id){
        this.setState({buttonId: id});
      }
    render(){
        return(
        <div>
             {this.state.buttonId === 1 && <Comic/>}
             {this.state.buttonId === 2 && <Contest/>}
             {this.state.buttonId !== 1  && this.state.buttonId !== 2 && <Comic/>}
             <input className={this.state.buttonId === 1? "button1 orange" : 
              "button1"} onClick={() => this.setButton(1)} value="Comic" 
               type="button" ref="button" />
            <input className={this.state.buttonId === 2? "button2 orange" : 
            "button2"} onClick={() => this.setButton(2)}  value="Contest" 
             ref="button1" type="button" />

         </div>
         );
       }
    }

export default Head;
```

Comment: Thanks . Its Working

Answer (score 0):

Your `.render` must return the components that you want to show.

So the code should look something like --

```
let component = this.state.buttonId === 2 ? <Contest/> : <Comic/>

return(
    <>
        {component}
        <div>
            {/* your button here */}      
        </div>
    </>
);
```