# How to return and render a component onClick()?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to render another class component through a button's onClick property. However when I call the function that returns the component (LogicGate). The function is called,  but nothing is visibly returned. Is there something fundamentally wrong with this logic. I am new to react.

**Below is the code:**

```
class TabMenuButtons extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {

        };
    }



    render() {
        function LogicGate (props) {
            console.log("LogicGate was called") 

            return <ComponentReturned/>

         }
        return (
            <div>
                <center>
                    <table cellspacing="30px">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                            <Button label="ITEM" icon="pi pi-home"  className="TabMenuButtons" onClick={accordionLogicGate}  style={{marginRight:'.25em', borderRadius: '8%',  backgroundColor: "#1c479c" }}></Button>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            <Button label="ITEM" icon="pi pi-users"  className="TabMenuButtons"    style={{marginRight:'.25em', borderRadius: '8%',  backgroundColor: "#1c479c"}}></Button>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            <Button label="ITEM" icon="pi pi-cloud"  className="TabMenuButtons"  style={{marginRight:'.25em', borderRadius: '8%',  backgroundColor: "#1c479c"}}></Button>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            <Button label="ITEM" icon="pi pi-money-bill" className="TabMenuButtons"   style={{marginRight:'.25em', borderRadius: '8%', backgroundColor: "#1c479c"}}></Button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </center>
                 <tr>
                    {/* EDIT THIS to become dynamic */}
                    <td className="StaticTextBelowTabView"><h1>  STATICTEXT: <em>$67,000.00 </em></h1> </td>
                    <td className="StaticTextBelowTabView"><h1> STATICTEXT: <em>$5,000.00</em>  </h1></td>
                    <td className="StaticTextBelowTabView"><h1> STATICTEXT: <em>$54,406.00</em> </h1></td>
                    <td className="StaticTextBelowTabView"><h1>  STATICTEXT: <em>1,000</em> </h1></td>
                    <td className="StaticTextBelowTabView"><h1> STATICTEXT: <em>20.00%</em></h1></td>
                </tr>
            </div>
        );
    }

}
```

**@Kenny (Multiple Component Issue):**

```
class TabMenuButtons extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            rendersummaryAccordions: false,
            renderservicesAccordions: false,
            rendertravelAccordions: false, 
            renderratesAccordions: false, 
        };

    }




   summaryAccordionsLogicGate = () => {
    this.setState({rendersummaryAccordions: true});
    console.log("summaryAccordionsLogicGate was called")

  } 

  servicesAccordionsLogicGate = () => {
    this.setState({renderservicesAccordions: true});
    console.log("servicesAccordionsLogicGate was called")

  } 

  ratesAccordionsLogicGate = () => {
    this.setState({renderratesAccordions: true});
    console.log("ratesAccordionsLogicGate was called")

  } 

  travelAccordionsLogicGate = () => {
    this.setState({rendertravelAccordions: true});
    console.log("travelAccordionsLogicGate was called")

  } 



    render() {
//The last ternary operator gets rendered for some reason, the rest will not be rendered onClick
        let componentPlaceHolder = null;
        this.state.rendersummaryAccordions ? componentPlaceHolder = <SummaryAccordions/> : componentPlaceHolder = null;
        this.state.renderservicesAccordions ? componentPlaceHolder = <ServicesAccordions/> : componentPlaceHolder = null;
        this.state.renderratesAccordions ? componentPlaceHolder = <RatesAccordions/> : componentPlaceHolder = null;
        this.state.rendertravelAccordions ? componentPlaceHolder = <TravelAccordions/> : componentPlaceHolder = null;
        return (
            <div>
                <center>
                    <table cellspacing="30px">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                            <Button label="SUMMARY" icon="pi pi-home"  className="TabMenuButtons" onClick={this.summaryAccordionsLogicGate}   style={{marginRight:'.25em', borderRadius: '8%',  backgroundColor: "#1c479c" }}></Button>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            <Button label="SERVICES" icon="pi pi-users"  className="TabMenuButtons" onClick={this.servicesAccordionsLogicGate}    style={{marginRight:'.25em', borderRadius: '8%',  backgroundColor: "#1c479c"}}></Button>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            <Button label="T&L/OPE" icon="pi pi-cloud"  className="TabMenuButtons" onClick={this.travelAccordionsLogicGate}  style={{marginRight:'.25em', borderRadius: '8%',  backgroundColor: "#1c479c"}}></Button>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            <Button label="RATES" icon="pi pi-money-bill" className="TabMenuButtons" onClick={this.ratesAccordionsLogicGate}   style={{marginRight:'.25em', borderRadius: '8%', backgroundColor: "#1c479c"}}></Button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </center>
                 <tr>

                    {/* EDIT THIS to become dynamic */}
                    <td className="StaticTextBelowTabView"><h1>  Item 0: <em>$67,000.00 </em></h1> </td>
                    <td className="StaticTextBelowTabView"><h1> Item 1: <em>$5,000.00</em>  </h1></td>
                    <td className="StaticTextBelowTabView"><h1> Item 2: <em>$54,406.00</em> </h1></td>
                    <td className="StaticTextBelowTabView"><h1>  Item 3: <em>1,000</em> </h1></td>
                    <td className="StaticTextBelowTabView"><h1> Item 4: <em>20.00%</em></h1></td>
                </tr>
                {componentPlaceHolder}
            </div>
        );
    }

}
```

Comment: you should use state, put the click handler on the class, and update a state value when the click happens. Based on that state value you can render the `ComponentReturned`.. aka `this.state.someValue ? <ComponentReturned /> : null`

Comment: Yes, the component will not be visible this way. What you need to do is set a state variable and show/hide the component based on its value. 

return <component> doesn't work in react

Comment: The idea being react needs to know that such a component might be rendered in this render()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conditional Rendering in React on button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50096032/conditional-rendering-in-react-on-button-click)

Comment: You're returning the component from your handler function, not your render function.

Comment: Also, don't put handlers in the render function, move them outside to the class level so they don't get recreated on every render.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example, did not try running it yet.

```
class TabMenuButtons extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
           logicComponent: false,
        };
    }



    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <center>
                    <table cellspacing="30px">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                            <Button label="ITEM" icon="pi pi-home"  className="TabMenuButtons" onClick={() => this.setState(logicComponent: !this.state.logicComponent)}  style={{marginRight:'.25em', borderRadius: '8%',  backgroundColor: "#1c479c" }}></Button>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            <Button label="ITEM" icon="pi pi-users"  className="TabMenuButtons"    style={{marginRight:'.25em', borderRadius: '8%',  backgroundColor: "#1c479c"}}></Button>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            <Button label="ITEM" icon="pi pi-cloud"  className="TabMenuButtons"  style={{marginRight:'.25em', borderRadius: '8%',  backgroundColor: "#1c479c"}}></Button>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            <Button label="ITEM" icon="pi pi-money-bill" className="TabMenuButtons"   style={{marginRight:'.25em', borderRadius: '8%', backgroundColor: "#1c479c"}}></Button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </center>
                 <tr>
                    {this.state.logicComponent ? <ComponentReturned/>:null}
                    {/* EDIT THIS to become dynamic */}
                    <td className="StaticTextBelowTabView"><h1>  STATICTEXT: <em>$67,000.00 </em></h1> </td>
                    <td className="StaticTextBelowTabView"><h1> STATICTEXT: <em>$5,000.00</em>  </h1></td>
                    <td className="StaticTextBelowTabView"><h1> STATICTEXT: <em>$54,406.00</em> </h1></td>
                    <td className="StaticTextBelowTabView"><h1>  STATICTEXT: <em>1,000</em> </h1></td>
                    <td className="StaticTextBelowTabView"><h1> STATICTEXT: <em>20.00%</em></h1></td>
                </tr>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: this wouldn't work, you are invoking setstate on each render cycle giving an infinite loop. click handlers need a callback function to then execute some code

Comment: Edited to make it onClick, my bad!

Answer (score 1):

This is another approach:

```
class TabMenuButtons extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
         loadComponent = false,
        };
      }

     loginGateHandler(){
         this.setState({loadComponent : !loadComponent});
     }

    render() {
        let componentPlaceHolder = null;
        this.state.loadComponent ? componentPlaceHolder = <ComponentReturned/> : componentPlaceHolder = null;
        return (
            <div>
                <center>
                    <table cellspacing="30px">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                            <Button label="ITEM" icon="pi pi-home"  className="TabMenuButtons" onClick={loginGateHandler}  style={{marginRight:'.25em', borderRadius: '8%',  backgroundColor: "#1c479c" }}></Button>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            <Button label="ITEM" icon="pi pi-users"  className="TabMenuButtons"    style={{marginRight:'.25em', borderRadius: '8%',  backgroundColor: "#1c479c"}}></Button>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            <Button label="ITEM" icon="pi pi-cloud"  className="TabMenuButtons"  style={{marginRight:'.25em', borderRadius: '8%',  backgroundColor: "#1c479c"}}></Button>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            <Button label="ITEM" icon="pi pi-money-bill" className="TabMenuButtons"   style={{marginRight:'.25em', borderRadius: '8%', backgroundColor: "#1c479c"}}></Button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </center>
                 <tr>
                 {componentPlaceHolder}
                    {/* EDIT THIS to become dynamic */}
                    <td className="StaticTextBelowTabView"><h1>  STATICTEXT: <em>$67,000.00 </em></h1> </td>
                    <td className="StaticTextBelowTabView"><h1> STATICTEXT: <em>$5,000.00</em>  </h1></td>
                    <td className="StaticTextBelowTabView"><h1> STATICTEXT: <em>$54,406.00</em> </h1></td>
                    <td className="StaticTextBelowTabView"><h1>  STATICTEXT: <em>1,000</em> </h1></td>
                    <td className="StaticTextBelowTabView"><h1> STATICTEXT: <em>20.00%</em></h1></td>
                </tr>
            </div>
        );
    }

}
```

I have not run this code, but I am pretty sure it is ready to go. Make sure you put the componentPlaceHolder where you want your component to be rendered in the page.

React components are not returned, but just rendered according to the logic you put in your code; you would manipulate the state variable to control all of this logic, and React will do the rest for you in terms of what is going to change in the DOM. Now, if you want to load just the contents of your component, as if it was a "new page", have a look at react-routing which is really straight forward. Likewise, I recommend you to start using ES6 features since it will make your life easier when working with React and JavaScript. Here is a good guide: https://medium.com/the-andela-way/a-beginners-guide-to-react-with-es6-a2ed0b5c977e

Good luck! :)

Comment: Hey I apreciate the help. I instituted your solution and I got the following error. VSCODE doesn't like where I placed the function. I'm posting a picture of it above

Comment: You don't need to use the `function` keyword inside of a class. `function loginGateHandler(){...}` should just be `loginGateHandler(){...}`

Comment: Ok thanks this works. I didn't originally post it in the question to avoid overcomplicating it, but I need to render multiple components based on this logic. When I implemented your code for multiple components only one of the ternary operators in the render method will actually render. I'll explain with images in my post

Comment: It is because you are using the same componentPlaceHolder varibale for all your components. You need to declare multiple variables to handle each component. Try something like let componentPlaceHolder1 = null; let componentPlaceHolder2 = null; let componentPlaceHolder3 = null; .... And handle each component logic separately.